# Extract part of string from URL in R

Tags: r, string, substring

Here's is the sample rows that I have. All I want is to extract website names, such as; 3dubs or adludio
How to do that? Cheers,

```
URL
https://www.3dhubs.com/
https://adludio.com/
https://aircall.io/
https://www.andjaro.com/en/home/
```

Result

```
3dhubs
adludio
aircall
andjaro
```

Once I typed this code,

```
suffix_extract(domain(df$URL))
```

I got the result as follows: When I tried to assigned it, it looks differently. How to get domain and assign to a column?

```
host            subdomain  domain   suffix
www.3dhubs.com  www        3dhubs   com
adludio.com     <NA>       adludio  com
```

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be safest to use a proper URL parser like the one from the `urltools` package. For example

```
dd$domain <- urltools::url_parse(dd$URL)$domain
```

Tested with

```
dd<-read.table(text="URL
https://www.3dhubs.com/
https://adludio.com/
https://aircall.io/
https://www.andjaro.com/en/home/", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: In fact suffix_extract(domain(df$URL)) gives me what I want in domain. However I can't assign the result to a column. Once I assigned it, that shows differently from console result.

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Same comment as on the other answer: using `gsub` to remove subdomains isn’t quite as straightforward as suggested in the answer. Using `suffix_extract` is probably safer.

Answer (score 0):

> How to get domain and assign to a column?

Using {urltools}, the following works for me:

```
df$domain = suffix_extract(domain(df$URL))$domain
```

Answer (score 0):

Library urltools should work. If your data is in object urls, this is what it returns.

```
library(urltools)
df1 <- suffix_extract(domain(urls))
df1
             host subdomain  domain suffix
1  www.3dhubs.com       www  3dhubs    com
2     adludio.com      <NA> adludio    com
3      aircall.io      <NA> aircall     io
4 www.andjaro.com       www andjaro    com

df1$domain
[1] "3dhubs"  "adludio" "aircall" "andjaro"
```

A dplyr / tidyr option is as follows, but with a `url_parse` from urltools to make sure it is a valid url.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data_frame(urls)

df %>% 
  mutate(url_parsed = urltools::url_parse(urls)$domain) %>% 
  separate(url_parsed, into = c("subdomain", "domain", "suffix"), fill = "left")

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  urls                             subdomain domain  suffix
  <chr>                            <chr>     <chr>   <chr> 
1 https://www.3dhubs.com/          www       3dhubs  com   
2 https://adludio.com/             NA        adludio com   
3 https://aircall.io/              NA        aircall io    
4 https://www.andjaro.com/en/home/ www       andjaro com
```

data:

```
urls <- c("https://www.3dhubs.com/", "https://adludio.com/", "https://aircall.io/", 
          "https://www.andjaro.com/en/home/")
```